# Label x-axis by days of the week

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I am trying to visualise data with a chart. I have done for hours, need to do for days and weeks to compare. Here is a sample code for the how I visualise hourly, having problems doing the same thing for day like monday, tuesday down to sunday in the intervals. How can I do this for day intervals?

```
chart1.ChartAreas.Add("area");
chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.Maximum = 24;
chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Maximum = intYAxisMax;
chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Interval= 10;

chart1.Series.Add("Electric");
chart1.Series.Add("Gas");

chart1.Series["Electric"].Color = Color.Red;
chart1.Series["Gas"].Color = Color.Green;

chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.Title = "Hours";
chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Title = "KW/H";

Title objTest = new Title("Daily Data Usage");
chart1.Titles.Add(objTest);

Legend objLegend = new Legend("Testing");
chart1.Legends.Add(objLegend);

//chart1.Series["Electric"].Points.AddXY(20 , 203);
//chart1.Series["Gas"].Points.AddXY(11, 70);
```

Comment: I appreciate that English may not be your first language, but please try to use some punctuation and proper sentence capitalization on here. It doesn't take much time, and you'll get a much more positive response from people if you put the effort in. Anyway, in response to the actual question, a screenshot of the graphs you have created so far would give us a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Most likely the datapoints were not added with x-vlaues as datetimes. if they were added correctly you could use the regular datatime formatting (`DDD`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
chart1.Series["Electric"].IsXValueIndexed = true;

//Add data
chart1.Series["Electric"].Points.AddXY(1, 203);
chart1.Series["Electric"].Points.AddXY(2, 70);

//X-axis labels
chart1.Series["Electric"].Points[0].AxisLabel = "Sunday";
chart1.Series["Electric"].Points[1].AxisLabel = "Monday";
```

etc...

Comment: thanks alot , but having this exception   Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: At what line? I'm assuming you have added 7 points of data to your "Electric" series...?

Comment: And also leave off all your AxisX min max interval stuff in the beginning

Comment: i added noting yet , just wanted to see this working first. the exception popped up here : chart1.Series["Electric"].Points[0].AxisLabel = "Sunday";   All the AxisX max and min stuff are all in comment too

Comment: Yeah you need to have data first, otherwise the chart1.Series["electric"].Points object is empty. See my edit

Comment: Glad it helped, no need to to thank though, rather just accept and vote up the solution.